# dealing with static list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have create a permission object that stores userId, Groups user is in and user´s permissions. This is a public class

I also need to have a static object that stores a list of those permissions objects that if a administration changes anything in the permissions all changes apply immediately for every logged user

I have a couple of questions:

1. Should I create this static object when the first user logs in or there is a mechanism a should use to create that list before the first user log-in (For instance when we start our app on IIS)?
2. Would it be easy to remove the item list for a specific user when it log-out?

This is a system requirement that permissions settings take effect as soon as the administrator make changes.

**Edit 1:**

```
public class permissionTemp
{
    public static Guid userGuid        { get; set; }
    public static string[] grupos      { get; set; }
    public static string[] permissoes  { get; set; }
}


public static class security
{
    public List<permissionTemp> userPermissionSet { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Are you persisting these permissions somewhere? What does the permission object look like?

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud Just updated my post and yes, permissions is in teh database

Comment: Maybe I'm not fully understanding, but it would appear that you are going to have to check the database for permissions for every request the user makes; to ensure that the permissions have not been modified by admin, and that the user is still authorized to view the page he/she just requested.

Comment: You could also consider automatically logging out a user if their permissions are changed.  If they are using the site when this happens they will be prompted to login again, then the new permissions can be loaded.  Possibly annoying for the user, depending on how often the permissions may change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can use the Application_Start method in the global.asax to run some code when the website starts for the first time. This will run before the first request is processed.
2. You can use the Session_End method in the global.asax to remove the item from the list. Also you can do it at the same time where you execute FormsAuthentication.SignOut (if you use Forms Authentication).

Note: I would use some locking mechanism to prevent multiple simultaneous access to the list. An alternative place to store the list would be in the WebCache. This is used by all users, so if it is updated by person x, next read from person y will be the updated version.

Comment: Perfect... This is what I was looking for. Read this object from the controle should not be difficult

Answer (score 2):

Think about a singleton, so you do not worry about creation time:

Singleton:

```
public class Permission
{
   private Permission()
   { }      

   private static Permission _instance = null;
   public static Permission Instance
   {
      get
      {
         if(_instance == null)
         {
            _instance = new Permission();
         }
         return _instance
      }
}
```

Now you can have access to the same instance with

```
Permission.Instance
```

The object is created at the first access. So in the private constructor you can add your code to read the permissions fom database.

Answer (score 0):

First of all i recommend to avoid creating static object for storing such sensetive information and also if any user has closed browser without clicking "Log out" then object will not be removed for that particular User.

Still if you need to do this to meet your requirement you can create it in that object in Applciation Start Event on Global.asax file when application start first time.